# How do I access properties on a joined ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

That was a badly-worded title, but I couldn't think of a clearer one, apologies.

I have an `Owner` model, with a `name` property. Owner `has_many :books` and Book `belongs_to :owner`. I am attempting to list all books and their owners. The intuitive way to do this would be `@books = Book.all`.

But each book instance only has `owner_id`, and I want to get that owner's *name*.

In SQL I would do

```
SELECT books.title, books.author, owners.name
FROM books
JOIN owners on owner.id = books.owner_id;
```

But I'm unsure of how to get all this data in one query using ActiveRecord, and Google isn't helping me. Could anyone point me to the right place in the docs or otherwise give me a tip?

I know you can do `owner.name` on each book instance, but that appears to do an additional database query, which seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on how associations work. Sure, on the db-record, the book only has an owner_id, but the `belongs-to` association lets you refer directly to the owner record - including all its attributes eg:

```
book.owner.name
```

This is the [Rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) - you should read it... and probably all the other rails guides too. You will learn a lot and it'll make your life so much easier :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll send this to my Kindle and read the whole thing tonight. I did try `book.owner.name` though, and my problem was that it seemed to query the database again for each individual name. To test, I made a page that lists all 850 books -- using `book.owner.title` it took 3.6 seconds to render. When I switched to my raw SQL query that dropped to 38ms. So surely hitting the database again for every property isn't the recommended practice?

Comment: it's the base for rails... unless you use joins - which will do it in one SQL query. `books = Book.joins(:owner).where ...` you just need to read further in the manual ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can preload associations using `includes`. This will load the association data in the same query.

```
@books = Book.includes(:owner).all
```

Side note:

Calling `book.owner.name` imposes a dependency for `book` on `owner.name`, which violates the [Law of Demeter](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/). Consider using [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) to implement `book.owner_name` instead.